# Remove an element from the arrayknowing its index

Tags: perl, grep

I have an array `@k`. I would like to create a new array `@j` that can copy the @k content but without the n-th element.

E.g. I have `@k=(1,1,1,3,4)`; I want that `@j` has all `@k`'s elements but not `k[2]`, i.e. `@j=(1,1,3,4);`

I tried with `@j=grep {$k[$_] != $k[$selectedIndex]} @k;` but in this it will select the value of the array and not his index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array slice to take only elements you want,

```
my @j = @k[0,1,3,4];
```

or use similar approach to filter out known elements,

```
my $selectedIndex = 2;
my @j = @k[ grep { $_ != $selectedIndex } 0..$#k ];
```

Comment: But the index that I must remove is not always the same. I must made it more general as possible

Comment: But it isn't customizable, may there are another way to do that.

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti do you have stored somewhere elements or indicies which should be filtered out?

Comment: The answer work. The only thing to do is to substitute the "2" with the generic `$selectedIndex` and it works.

Comment: Everybody keeps suggesting "splice".  Maybe I'm dumb, but "splice" doesn't take an element out of the middle, it gives one either everything before the index, or everything on or after the index.  Seems like duplicating your second suggestion would require two splices.

Comment: `splice ARRAY,OFFSET,LENGTH` can actually remove elements from an array at OFFSET position. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice

Answer (score 7):

Use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).

```
my @j = @k;
my $idx = 2;
splice @j, $idx, 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this "fast" solution

```
@k = (2,4,6,8,10);

$index_that_i_dont_want = 2;
@j = ();
$k_size = @k;
foreach $i (0..$k_size) {
    push (@j, $k[$i]) if($i != $index_that_i_dont_want);
}
#checks if it's right
foreach $val (@j) {
    print "$val\n";
}
```

Comment: Better the splice solution of Chris :)

Comment: `$k_size = @k` should be `$k_size = $#k` to ensure we loop through the correct number of indexes.